# how can i point the shell go execute an activity that is stored in an rList?

Tags: android, shell, command

I am trying to lauch an application in Android from the terminal emulator (on device) normally this command would work.

```
am start -n com.hcg.cok.gp/com.hcg.cok.gp.com.clash.of.kings.EmpireActivity
```

The problem I am having is the developer decided to nest the activity in an rList, it took forever to even find the stupid thing but finally after changing directories enough times and using the

```
ls 
ls -a
```

Commands enough times I finally found the dumb thing in the directory planted like this

```
/data/data/com.hcg.cok.gp/files/rList-com.clash.of.kings.EmpireActivity
```

Is there any way to get the

```
am start -n
```

Command to call the dumb thing properly

I have tried

```
am start -n /data/data/com.hcg.cok.gp/com.hcg.com.gp/files/rlist-com.clash.of.kings.EmpireActivity
```

But the terminal still gives me an error:

```
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {/data/data/com.hcg.cok.gp/com.hcg.com.gp/files/rlist-com.clash.of.kings.EmpireActivity} does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package name of the `EmpireActivity` is `com.clash.of.kings`, so the correct `intent` is:

```
am start -n com.hcg.cok.gp/com.clash.of.kings.EmpireActivity
```

Comment: I have also tried it this way, it doesn't work, after doing a dumpsys activity activities command it looks like the activity requires a specific defined user to call the intent, is there anyway to specify these kinds of things with flags?

Comment: Well that's weird, I decided to give it a second try, I must have spelled something wrong the first fifty times I tried this. It worked this time, thanks!!

Comment: Feeling pretty dumb now. Lol thanks again, your a life saver now my game actions are automated with an incoming text from a team mate, I won't have to touch my phone at all while on vacation. You rock man!